# this.props.fetch is not a function redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

props.notificationList is not a function? How can i solved it?

I use single-spa framework problem is that seems like this.props.fetch is not working but if I'm using simple react-app is working properly. I'm using react typscript and single-spa

```
export class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(): void {
    this.props.notificationList()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="notification-ui-app">
        {console.log(this.props.notificationList)}
        <Dropdown>
          <Dropdown.Toggle size="sm" variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
            [sadfsf ]
          </Dropdown.Toggle>

          <Dropdown.Menu>
            {/* {notices} */}
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state: any) => {
  return { notifications: state.notifications }
}

const mapDispatchprops = (dispatch: any) => {
 return { 
 notificationList: () => dispatch(fetchAllNotification()),
 }
}
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchprops)(App);
```

```
export const fetchAllNotification = () => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        return fetch('/notifications?userId=5dc12ec726ccb32110925487')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => dispatch(
                { type: "FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS", notifications: json }
                ))
            .catch(err => dispatch(
                { type: "ERROR",msg: "Unable to fetch data" }))
    }
}
```

Comment: it's `this.props.NotificationList` (with a capital) since that's how it's defined in `mapDispatchprops`.

Comment: @Clarity sorry I already edited it's supposed to be small n but even that it's not working I think it's not naming problem

Comment: the code as you posted it should work. The issue is probably somewhere else, e.g. in the way `App` component is used, or `fetchAllNotification` is imported incorrectly, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I try to check all the way on how I import and I found the problem. I post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it by changing this line of code

```
export class App extends React.Component<Props, State>
```

to

```
 class App extends React.Component<Props, State>
```

then

```
import { App }
```

to

```
import App
```